# Azure vm public ip?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

we need to access our partner's sql azure db, they ask for an ip so they add to the whitelist, thing is we doing the dev work on our azure vm (under different subscription), what ip should we give them, I suppose a public IP address? Will that change over time?

Thanks advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM public IP will not change unless all the VMs in that cloud service (the service holding the public IP) are stop/deallocated. Restarting the VM won't change the IP either.

I usually shutdown my VM very carefully to prevent accidentally changing my IP addresses. So far for past few years, I just tried once unintended change.

---

*Note:*

You may also consider the newly introduced [**Reserved IP**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) to reserve an IP and prevent it from changing. However,

> [a]t this time, you can’t reserve an IP address for a cloud service
>   that you have already created.

which means you could only reserve a new IP address if you would like to use **Reserved IP**.

Comment: I used the reserved ip feature which is quite neat, the ip is reserved even a vm is shutdown